# Alterar URL Requisição Ajax PartialView

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou precisando alterar a URL da página de acordo com a PartialView que carrego via Ajax.

**@EDIT**

Além disso, também preciso liberar o acesso direto a PartialView via URL, mas, trazendo consigo a página "pai" pois trabalho com ela de modo que a mesma exerce funções da MasterPage, ou seja, carrego nela scripts e layout.
Queria evitar de importar em cada página meus scripts.

**Resolvido adicionando $('#rodape').load('/Web/Rodape'); para renderizar uma PartialView como rodapé**

Possuo o seguinte código em minha View

```
 <div class="conteudo">
 <!-- Conteudo regular do site -->
 </div>
 <div id="corpoConteudo"></div>
```

via Ajax, carrego o conteudo das `PartialView` dentro da `<div id="corpoConteudo">`

Meu script é esse

```
    function Open(url) {
        Carregar();
        url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + url;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#corpoConteudo').html(response);
                $('#loader').remove();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Ocorreu um erro!');
                $('#loader').remove();
            }
        });
    }

    function Carregar() {
        $('#corpoConteudo').append('<div id="loader"></div>');
    }
```

Comment: "Trazer consigo a página pai", a meu ver, é chamar a página pai. No MVC não se chama o conteúdo filho para trazer o conteúdo pai, e sim o contrário. É justamente por isso que o Razor não possui o conceito de `MasterPage`, e sim, o conceito de Layout. Quais são as páginas que você precisará chamar? Poderia por favor melhorar sua resposta?

Comment: Basicamente minha página Index é tratada como uma MasterPage, pois nela dou o header, nav e o footer. No meio dela, na div id="corpoConteudo", trago minhas PartialView. Por exemplo: Case, Noticias e assim por diante.
Acessando: http://localhost:3245/ vou direto para Index e posteriormente clicando em um elemento, navego pelas PartialView. Se acesso: http://localhost:3245/Web/Case, sendo Web meu Controller e Case a PartialView, não carrego os elementos (Header, Nav, Footer) pois estão em minha Index. Gostaria de fazer essa contra mão e além disso, atualizar a URL com a PartialView que carrego.

Comment: Então, a meu ver isso é um problema de abordagem. O certo seria o `Ajax` carregar outra `Action` (que traga apenas a Partial), e as `Actions` padrão utilizem `Views` pai que carreguem o Layout por completo.

Comment: Entendo e te dou razão. No mais, editei a minha pergunta com a solução que encontrei para tratar o problema do modo em que o projeto se encontra.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, substituindo as Partials por Views, não é mais necessário usar uma Partial que só carregue o rodapé, pois o rodapé já estará contido no Layout. Usando um Layout, para toda chamada de Action, irá carregar a página inteira, assim não está fazendo com que itens que já foram carregados carregue de novo?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo E qual é o problema nisso? Se eu fizer uma requisição não-ajax, eu tenho que retornar a página toda de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso é implementar `Actions` que só respondam Ajax. Para isso, implemente um atributo que só responda Ajax, mais ou menos assim:

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute 
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

Decore sua `Action` da seguinte forma:

```
[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult Rodape()
{
   ...
}
```